# При подгрузке 3D модели на сайт через model-viewer сервер возвращает 403

Tags: javascript, html

> Error: fetch for "https://neir0n.xyz/logo2.glb" responded with 403: at
> model-viewer.js:34482:12

Я впервые использую model-viewer на хостинге, до этого только локалка, там как раз всё хорошо.
В файле .htaccess никаких запретов к .glb не применяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил, просто нужно было изменить права доступа к файлу на хостинге..